# Как правильнее?

Tags: синтаксис

Как правильно: узел в груди у Северуса или же Узел в груди Северуса?

Answer (score 2):

Нам часто приходится выбирать из двух подобных вариантов, например: глаза юноши - глаза у юноши. Это два значения падежа: притяжательный беспредложный и предложный со значением сопричастности. 
Думаю, что вариант "глаза у юноши", грудь у Северуса" используется в том случае, когда мы переносим наше внимание на предметы (глаза, грудь), в то время как их носитель отодвигается на второй план, просто сопричастен этим предметам.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе, большой разницы нет, но, если Вы хотите сделать акцент на том, что грудь принадлежала именно Снейпу, то лучше сказать "у Северуса". А если это и так понятно, и речь изначально шла о нем, то "у" можно опустить.

Comment: Я тоже думаю, что оба варианта в принципе верны: часто ведь в литературе можно прочитать и "в руке у него было", и "в его руке было". Правда, мне кажется, что первый вариант больше характерен для разговорного стиля (прошу, однако, учесть, что это сугубо мое личное мнение).  

Answer (score -1):

В данном случае можно и так и этак, но бывают более сложные случаи, и выбор варианта зависит от музыки звучания текста. Да и в данном случае второй вариант предпочтительнее (с музыкальной точки зрения). Впрочем, хороший писатель, составляя фразу, уже "прослушивает" её, и, как правило, такие вопросы на нашем Высоком форуме из "хорошего" текста не появятся.